# What is the difference between two EL syntaxes?

Tags: java, jsp, el

I want to make form fields stable in JSP forms so I use:

```
${param.fieldName}
```

I tried to make like this:

```
${param["fieldame"]}
```

and also works!

Can someone tell me what is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Expression Language Specification Version 2.2 Maintenance Release](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html):

> **1.6 Operators `[]` and `.`**
>
> `expr-a.identifier-b` is equivalent to
>   `expr-a["identifier-b"]`; that is, the
>   identifier identifier-b is used to
>   construct a literal whose value is the
>   identifier, and then the `[]` operator
>   is used with that value.

Answer (score 2):

In the `param["fieldName"]` you can have *any* (valid) string between the quotes.  In the param.fieldName you cannot have that, as it can only contain the characters that are valid for an identifier.

In both cases it maps to a lookup.  What kind of lookup depends on what type "param" resolves to.

Comment: in both cases the field name should be valid, but in para["fieldname"] the field name can be created dynamically ! Am I correct?

Comment: @Alaa, I'm not sure.  I know, however, that the two form for syntax map down to the same lookup operation.